# Bananas! What are they for?

Tags: diddy-kong-racing

I've heard that collecting bananas increases your speed, is this true? 
I don't seem to speed up when I get a bunch. Although that may be because the speed of each one is too subtle to notice.

Comment: [Absolutely nothing!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dpWmlRNfLck)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They do marginally increase your speed, but I have never noticed it being that much of an increase. Also, the increase stops at ten bananas - you can theoretically collect more than that, but they won't help you.

As Toomai pointed out in comments, you can use the VITAMINB cheat, which allows you to collect an unlimited amount of bananas.

Comment: Unless you use the VITAMINB cheat, which I believe removes the 10-banana limit.

Comment: Some of the more difficult races are quite challenging without loading up on bananas.  The speed change might not be noticeable but the difference in final time can be measured ;)

Comment: I'm sorry, 'never noticed it being much of an increase'?  The difference between 0 and 10 bananas is *substantial*.

Comment: @GnomeSlice perhaps. But I never noticed it.

Comment: Also, there's another cheat, 'BOGUSBANANAS' that makes bananas you pick up *slow you down* rather than speed you up.

Comment: Everytime you get hit or run into an obstruction (except oil spills) you lose 2 bananas

Answer (score 7):

Collecting Bananas increases your speed by a small amount.  It's unclear whether or not each single banana increases your speed slightly, or if it increases every 2, 3 bananas, etc.  You'll stop speeding up after you grab 10, but having extra is good insurance against attacks.

There are also three cheat codes that relate to bananas:

**VITAMINB:**  There is no longer a speed bonus cap of 10 bananas

**BOGUSBANANAS:**  Collected bananas cause you to *slow down* rather than speed up.

As far as I can know, these two cheats are stackable.

Also there is **FREEFRUIT** which gives you 10 bananas at the start of the race.

Comment: Best answer. Also, everytime you get hit or run into an obstruction (except oil spills) you lose 2 bananas

Answer (score 0):

The bananas slowly increase you speed but mainly if you hit a zipper the boost effect is longer then with less bananas so by speed it up means longer boost. I don't know if it works with the blue balloons but hit a zipper with no bananas and then with a few and see the difference:)